# Android App migrating to 64 bit missing 64-bit folders

Tags: android, kotlin, 64-bit

Since 1 august your app has to be 64 bit supported.
Now I have a problem because our app isn't 64 bit supported.

I follow the steps of the Android Documentation (https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) about 64 bit and when I analyze my apk I see this:

[image]

So I don't see the 64 bit folders "lib/arm64-v8a" en "lib/x86_64".
I added this line in my gradle defaultConfig `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`

My minSdkVersion is **16**
My targetSdkVersion is **28**
My compileSdkVersion is **28**

Hopefully someone can help me what to do... I want to upload a update of my app in de store soon.

Comment: I need to know this too...